# can i bake cloth simulation results to an animation drive by armature?

Tags: armature, bones, cloth-simulation

I have read some tutorial about cloth simulation,and i know how to use cloth simulation with a mesh drive by armature.Then,i what to do something like this:
(1) i have a character mesh with armature,and this mesh has several parts like body,cloth....
(2) i create cloth simulation with cloth part in my mesh,and its works well
**(3) i want to bake the cloth simulation result(vertices deformation) to bones transformation,then i could use skeletal animation to reproduce the results of cloth simulation**
(4) export only skeletion animation
I want to know if blender provides the above function and how to use it if so

Comment: I have seen something like this done in game development, particularly in unused animations in portal 2 where a blanket is retracted into the wall. Maybe ask their forum if no answers here? But anyway, my best guess is basically to have a grid of bones in place of various points on the fabric, following its vertices around and recording the points’ animations as keyframes. This is probably possible through some fairly simple API. There might be an ad on somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I am trying to use this method to make clothing animations which be used to game engine. Currently, I am trying to get the estimated position of the bones in each frame to reproduce simulation result in an optimized way.